# Aperte workflow integrating with lifaray 6.1.1 CE

Tags: liferay

I am using liferay-portal-tomcat-6.1.1-ce-ga2.Now i want to integrate aperte work flow to the portal.i know that aperte bundle is available with liferay 6.0.6.
but i need aperte workflow  for liferay 6.1.1 CE.
how i can achieve this?
help me..thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to get the Aperte Workflow code base and maven build with liferay 6.1 dependency. Then solve the issue one by one. 
Few days back I have done a research on that and successfully made it work.
The entire process is documented on my blog. 
Here is the link, 
http://rupalchatterjee.wordpress.com/2013/07/03/integrate-aperte-workflow-in-liferay-6-1/